# .Net Core 2.1 Socket Server

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is there a proper implementation of a socket server available for .Net Core 2.1 (2.0). By "proper" I mean the one that deals with all the underlying low-level details, such as connection handling, data reading, etc.

Is it possible to use something like Kestrel server to read/write raw socket data without HTTP headers?

Comment: Do you mean websockets?

Comment: For .net core 2.1 the underlying socket implementation for kestrel was rewritten, maybe you can use it in your project: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets/

Comment: Maybe old good `TcpListener`/`TcpClient`?

Comment: This might be of interest https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1980

Comment: @davidfowl, funnily enough, I've created this question after reading through that page :) as I understand it's not yet implemented? I.e. it's impossible right now to use Kestrel that does not add/expect anything to the response/request, purely passes on raw data to a middleware?

Comment: It is, it isn't well documented yet though. Let me get you a sample

Comment: We need a clean high performance reference implementation of the new sockets using span. Both synchronous and asynchronous with understanding the pros and cons. Can we achieve near 10gbps on C# managed sockets with zero-copy?

Comment: @davidfowl so how about that sample? :)

Comment: @davidfowl, I was able to build a working socket server with just what is available in Kestrel 2.1 by taking bits and pieces of signalr code. It's not as good as the proposal, but works well.